# why EXPECT_EQ can not rightly accept the result of method as a parameter?

Tags: c++, googletest

[image]
I am learning data structure so I made a Stack class via template and use gtest to test it.

While in the 2 ways using EXPECT_EQ macro it shows difference testing result.

1. In this way, the last line triggered the exception ONLY in the condition that I use "RUN" configure instead of "DEBUG" configure. And I found that it always happens in the last `stack->pop` method as long as I totally clear the stack and there are more than one elements in the stack.

```cpp
TEST(Stack,isOK){
    auto stack = new Stack<int>();
    stack->Push(123);
    stack->Push(123);
    stack->Push(123);
    auto ret = stack->Pop();
    EXPECT_EQ(ret, 123);
    EXPECT_EQ(stack->Pop(), 123);
    EXPECT_EQ(stack->Pop(), 123);  // this line.
}
```

And the exception shows that:

```
Running main() from D:\Homework\DataStructure\C++\Test\lib\googletest-master\googletest\src\gtest_main.cc
Running 1 test from 1 test suite.D:\Homework\DataStructure\C++\Test\tests\StackTest.cpp:15: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  stack->Pop()
    Which is: -2147483136
  123

1 test from 1 test suite ran. (1 ms total)
```

2. In this way, all code goes well.

```cpp
TEST(Stack,isOK){
    auto stack = new Stack<int>();
    stack->Push(123);
    stack->Push(123);
    stack->Push(123);
    auto ret = stack->Pop();
    EXPECT_EQ(ret, 123);
    EXPECT_EQ(stack->Pop(), 123);
    ret = stack->Pop();
    EXPECT_EQ(ret, 123);  // ALL IS OK.
}
```

Stack.h

```cpp
//
// Created by anon on 2019/4/15.
//

#ifndef DATA_STRUCTURE_STACK_H
#define DATA_STRUCTURE_STACK_H

#include "Definition.h"

template<class T>
class Stack {
    const int stack_init_size = 1;
    const int stack_increment = 1;

protected:
    T *base;
    T *top;
    int stack_size;
public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    Status          Clear();
    bool            empty();
    int             length();
    T               GetTop();
    Status          Push(T e);
    T               Pop();
};

template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack() {
    stack_size = stack_init_size;
    base = (T *)malloc(sizeof(T) * stack_size);
    top = base;
}

template<class T>
Status Stack<T>::Clear() {
    return 0;
}

template<class T>
bool Stack<T>::empty() {
    return false;
}

template<class T>
int Stack<T>::length() {
    if (top == nullptr) {
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        auto val = (top - base);
        return val;
    }
}

template<class T>
Status Stack<T>::Push(T e) {
    if (length() == stack_size){
        auto old_base = base;

        base = (T *)realloc(base,(stack_size + stack_increment)* sizeof(T));
        if (!base) exit(ERROR);
        if (base != old_base){
            top = base + (stack_size * sizeof(T));
        }
        stack_size += stack_increment;
    }
    *top = e;
    top++;
    return OK;
}

template<class T>
T Stack<T>::Pop() {
    if (length() == 0)
        exit(ERROR);
    auto ret = *(top-1);
    top--;
    return ret;
}

template<class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack() {
    delete base;
}

template<class T>
T Stack<T>::GetTop() {
    if (length() == 0)
        exit(ERROR);
    return *(top-1);
}


#endif //DATA_STRUCTURE_STACK_H
```

Comment: It can, you just have a bug somewhere. Why do you push the same value? Try pushing different once for better testing and check the result.

Comment: `stack->Pop()` has side effects and `EXPECT_EQ` is a macro. There's no guarantee that `stack->Pop()` is getting called only once for everytime you call `EXPECT_EQ`. The more natural way is `EXPECT_EQ(123, stack->Pop());` and if I recall correctly this way only calls `stack->Pop()` once although it evaluates 123 several times (which doesn't have side effects).

Comment: This `top = base + (stack_size * sizeof(T));` looks fishy. `base` is a T*. `base+X` is then `X*sizeof(T)` bytes away from `base`, `base + (X*sizeof(T))` looks meaningless. But more importantly: why are you writing C code instead of C++?

Comment: And your length is (top - base) +1 !! (not top-base, or you have a bug in your constructor)

Comment: @Gojita I think not. At construction, `top == base`, `top-base` is then `0` which is expected of an empty stack ;)

Comment: @YSC becasue  I am new to c++ and the book I learn from using a cstyle c++. And the reason I wrote `top = base + (stack_size * sizeof(T));` is that once realloc creates a new memory the top pointer becomes a fake one, so I have to reset it. And all these I test OK, but the problem is about the EXPECT_EQ statement instead of the code itself.

Comment: @Anon no it is not. Since your a beginner I'll give you a valuable lesson I learned the hard way. When faced with an unexpected behavior: **you** are wrong. The library you're using is right, the compiler is right, the OS is right, the CPU is right. **you** are wrong. Repeat it until it's hard coded in your brain. Fix your code ;)

Comment: @YSC Of cource I am wrong.But I have no knowledge to fix the problems that different configure settings (DEBUG and RUN) cause different results.

Comment: @Mirko But I tried `EXPECT_EQ(123,stack->Pop());` as the last statement.The issue still occurs. /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Comment: @Anon, YSC is right, you are testing your code more or less correctly (maybe push different numbers to your Stack to test it better), but your implementation for sure has a bug that manifests in [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), which you describe as "different configure settings (DEBUG and RUN) cause different results". Now debug your code. For memory issues (like out of bound access) I recommend `valgrind`.

Comment: @YSC Thanks very much I finally understand what you mean(O(∩_∩)O I am not a Native English Speaker). The bug is `top = base + (stack_size * sizeof(T));` and only  in "RUN" setting realloc always create a new space of memory which triggers this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following for your push method:

```
template<class T>
Status Stack<T>::Push(T e) {
  if (length() == stack_size) {
    stack_size += stack_increment;
    base = (T *)realloc(base, stack_size * sizeof(T));
    if (!base) std::exit(ERROR);
    top = base + stack_size;
  }
  *top++ = e;
  return OK;
}
```

When you add an integer `x` to a pointer of type `T*`, it does not literally increase the value of the pointer by `x`. It moves the pointer `x` "slots to the right", where one "slot" is the space occupied by one `T`.

So when you write `top = base + stack_size;` then the actual value of `top` is `base + (stack_size * sizeof(T))`.

For more information, Google "pointer arithmetic" or see [this reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm)